# Hide/Encrypt hidden form in HTML

Tags: html, security

I have created hidden form and it will be contain hidden input and javascript submit. But while form is submitted, user can view the source of page and will know all values of it. How can I hide this form or encrypt it so that user can not know values from even source of html.

Comment: Don't store sensitive data, encrypted or not, in your HTML source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* encrypt the data (using standard strong encryption) on the server and store the result in the form.

Standard practise, however, is to not give sensitive data to the client in the first place. Store the data on the server, associate it with a token, then give that token to the client.

Sessions are the standard approach for doing that.

Comment: I am agree to you but in my case client is third party and can not modify his flow. Anyways, it's possible best answer !

Answer (score 2):

If this information is sensitive, don't post it on the page at all.

Keep the data on the server and have a token to correlate the request with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Maybe you can hide stuff from an average user, but given enough skills data that's available to the user can be read / manipulated by the user. The right practice is to store data at the server and associate it with a user.

For example, you can have a look at [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).